# How to debug when requiring a particular Ruby gem is halting execution?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am working on writing a gem. One of the gems that I am dependent on is halting execution of the file that requires it. Here is an example:

```
# main.rb
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
puts 'Going to do something now...'
Mygem::Nested::Thing.do_something

# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'mygem', path: './mygem'

# mygem.gemspec
...
spec.add_dependency 'mygem-dependency'
...

# mygem.rb
puts 'Loading mygem.rb'
require_relative 'mygem/nested/thing'
puts 'Finished loading my gem.rb'

# mygem/nested/thing.rb
puts 'Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb'
require 'mygem-dependency'
module Mygem
  module Nested
    class Thing
      def self.do_something
        MygemDependency.do_something
      end
    end
  end
end
puts 'Finished loading mygem/nested/thing.rb'
```

When I run my script, loading is halted when I try and load the dependent gem:

```
$ bundle exec ruby main.rb
Loading mygem.rb
Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Going to do something now...
main.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Mygem::Nested (NameError)
```

It never finishes loading the rest of my gem. However, it seems to continue executing everything after `Bundler.require`. If I comment-out the line that requires the dependent gem, everything works as expected except the line which depends on the other gem.

```
$ bundle exec ruby main.rb
Loading mygem.rb
Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading my gem.rb
Going to do something now...
mygem/nested/thing.rb:7:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Mygem::Nested::Thing::MygemDependency (NameError)
```

If I move the require statement into the body of the method, I get a load error:

```
module Mygem
  module Nested
    class Thing
      def self.do_something
        require 'mygem-dependency'
        MygemDependency.do_something
      end
    end
  end
end

$ bundle exec ruby main.rb
Loading mygem.rb
Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading my gem.rb
Going to do something now...
mygem/nested/thing.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- mygem-dependency (LoadError)
```

There isn't a problem with the gem because I can use it directly. For some reason, I'm having issues when trying to use it within my gem. How can I figure out the problem and fix it?

Comment: It looks like bundler.require rescues some load errors ( https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb ) - Working out why requiring mygem-dependency raises (and if bundler is indeed swallowing that) would be step 1

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks! That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How to debug when requiring a particular Ruby gem is halting execution

Pick any error, and try to solve the problem.  Repeat until you don't get any more errors.  The more experience you acquire, the better you'll know where to begin.  When you get an error like this:

```
main.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Mygem::Nested (NameError)
```

I would check:

1. Have you actually defined something that starts with `Mygem::Nested`?
2. Did you misspell the name in one of your require statements?  Should it actually be `MyGem::Nested`?
3. Is your require statement using the correct syntax?  In other words, do you need to use a full path, a relative path, or just the name of the file?

Your code actually works for me:

```
$ tree .
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── main.rb
├── mygem
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── mygem
│   │   │   └── nested
│   │   │       └── thing.rb
│   │   └── mygem.rb
│   └── mygem.gemspec
└── your_main.rb
```

main.rb:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

#Bundler.setup(:default)
#require 'mygem'

Mygem::Nested::Thing.do_something
```

mygem.gemspec:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'mygem'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2015-02-12'
  s.summary     = "A new internet!"
  s.description = "Creates a new internet that is completely secure."
  s.authors     = ["7stud"]
  s.email       = '7@new.i.com'
  s.files       = [
    "lib/mygem.rb",
    "lib/mygem/nested/thing.rb",
  ]
  s.homepage    = 'http://rubygems.org/gems/mygem'
  s.license     = 'GNU Public'

  s.add_dependency 'nokogiri' 
end
```

lib/mygem.rb:

```
puts 'Loading mygem.rb'
require_relative 'mygem/nested/thing'
puts 'Finished loading my gem.rb'
```

lib/mygem/nested/thing.rb:

```
puts 'Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb'

require 'nokogiri'  #Your gem's dependency, which is added to .gemspec file

module Mygem
  module Nested
    class Thing
      def self.do_something
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div>hello</div>')
        puts doc.at_xpath('//div/text()')
      end
    end
  end
end

puts 'Finished loading mygem/nested/thing.rb'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'mygem', path: './mygem'
```

Result:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin10.0]

$ ruby main.rb 
Loading mygem.rb
Loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading mygem/nested/thing.rb
Finished loading my gem.rb
hello
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's different here...just Bundler.setup and explicitly require instead of Bundler.require?

Comment: Hmm...yes.  Your code actually works for me--error free.  I'll post my files, so you can compare them to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the "extension" gem that I was using (`mygem-dependency`) did not provide a file named `mygem-dependency.rb` in its `lib` directory. So instead of requiring `mygem-dependency` I needed to require `mygem/dependency`.

The other problem was that Bundler was silencing the load errors for dependencies within gems specified in the `Gemfile`. https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L49